# change captcha to Arial Font and delete Background image

Tags: magento2, captcha

Is it possible to change the captcha on my website [agoshop.at](https://agoshop.at) to Arial Font and to delete the background image.
I use rokanthemes.
I find this site: https://magento-qa.com/magento-2-how-to-change-default-captcha-font-color-background

But I don't have a folder Captcha which should be in:
magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Captcha/Image.php

I can find an image.php file in folder: vendor/zendframework/zend-captcha/src/Image.php

Which code I must change or delete in this file?

and also I don't have a folder Company for the font which should be in:
app/code/Company/Module/etc/config.xml

When I search for config.xml I will get the following differnt results:

[image]

I have find in file vendor\magento\moduel-captcha\etc\config.xml the definition of LinLibertineFont and add there the font Arial like:

```
<arial>
   <label>Arial</label>
   <path>ArialFont/ArialCE.ttf</path>
</arial>
```

Also I copy the ArialCE.ttf into the folder
vendor\magento\magento2-base\lib\internal\ArialFont

But I cannot choose the Arial Font in the customer configuration of captcha only LinLibertine.

Hope someone can help me. kindly regards

Comment: What folders do you have _then_?

Comment: Which Magento version do you have to use?

Comment: Hi!
I use Magento ver. 2.3.4.